# How do I run python from Sublime text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I just got python and sublime 3. When I press control + b, I get this in the console:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

And it won't run my amazing code!

```
print"Hi"
```

I do have Python installed, and how do I change the PATH?

Comment: Do you have Python installed?

Comment: You likely need to add python to your system `PATH`

Comment: Sounds like your on Windows, so try this [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/1248974)

Comment: Add the full path to `python.exe` in Sublime Text so it doesn't have to search.

Comment: When you installed Python, you should have been asked if you wanted it added to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I didn't get asked anything...

Comment: @downshift that's not the problem. OP needs to add Python's home directory to the Windows `PATH`. `PYTHONPATH` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @MattDMom great thanks for pointing that out, perhaps [How To Add Python to the Windows Path](http://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path) will better help the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed Python 2, you'll need to just go ahead and install Python 3, as it's the present and future of the language. Don't starting learning Python with 2, you'll pick up all sorts of bad habits. Learn with 3, then go back and find out the differences with 2 when you can understand them. I'm assuming you're on a 64-bit system, as everything is these days, so download Python 3 from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/python-3.5.1-amd64.exe). If you're not, get [this one](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/python-3.5.1.exe). Run the installer, and pick the option (I forget exactly where it is) that says "Add Python to my PATH". Finish the installation, restart Sublime, and it should pick up `python.exe` just fine.

BTW, in Python 3, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function, so your first code to run should be

```
print("Hi!")
```

Don't forget to save the file before building.

Oh yeah, avoid "Learn Python the Hard Way" like **the plague**. [It sucks](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). Instead, read the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial) first, then pick something [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) and/or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/wiki/index).

Comment: I found two tutorials that both use python 2, so I uninstalled 3, because all the learning things were for two. So fine, I'll get 3.

Comment: @CJ: Don't. Your question, *as it stands*, got answered.

Comment: @Rad Lexus Don't what?

Comment: @CJ. BTW, you can have both 2 and 3 installed at the same time. I just strongly recommend using 3 primarily.

Comment: @CJ: change your question to something entirely new. Stack Overflow is a site for *questions* and *answers*. After getting an answer, you changed the question to ask something new, which invalidated the answer.